# Websockets request-response mapping

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

Is there a way to map a request with a response from server? It seems that Websocket doesn't provide anything.

I don't want to use a third library so it has to be in plain javascript (or at least with jquery).

I would implement a message id. When i send something the generated message id will be prepended to the message and the server will give the response with this message id so i'm able to map on the client side.

Any better ideas?

Comment: Have a look at [JSON-RPC](http://www.jsonrpc.org/). The spec is quite straight forward and you can easily implement it (over WebSockets) on your own.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/wyre

Answer (score 0):

I am working on open sourcing our companies solution for this.  I will update this answer when it is available.

Update: It is production ready and we are currently using it.  However the open source process is extremely slow right now!

Update: My company took too long.  I wrote it from scratch without using the old one as reference.  It's a little different but it should work great! It's called wyre. you can check it out on npm. https://www.npmjs.com/package/wyre. Let me know what you think